# ¿Cómo sustituyo el primer array por el segundo?

Tags: java, array, matrices, array-bidimensional

Tengo un primer array con los números: 1 2 3 4
Y un segundo array con la suma de los num que cumplan i!=j, esto es :9 8 7 6
¿Cómo sustituyo los valores del primer array por los del segundo? de manera que el segundo array ahora pueda contener las sumas de los números 9 8 7 6.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Introduzca el numero de casillas del arreglo: ");
int n = sc.nextInt();
System.out.print("Introduzca el número de fases: ");
int k = sc.nextInt();

int primerArray[] = new int[n];
int segundoArray[] = new int[n];

for (int fase = 0; fase < k; fase++) {
for (int i = 0; i < primerArray.length; i++) {
    primerArray[i] = i + 1;
}
//ciclo de fases
    
    for (int i = 0; i < segundoArray.length; i++) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < primerArray.length; j++) {
            if (i != j) {
                sum = sum + primerArray[j];
            }
        }
        segundoArray[i] = sum;
        System.out.println(primerArray[i] + " - " + segundoArray[i]);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Haz que `primerArray` ahora apunte a `segundoArray`, o sea `primerArray = segundoArray;`. Luego vuelve a construir el `segundoArray` o sea `segundoArray = new int[primerArray.length];` y repite el ciclo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes extraer el código de ciclo de fases a una función y pasar los arreglos como parámetros. Para invertir el resultado se puede invertir el orden de los parámetros:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class Test {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Introduzca el numero de casillas del arreglo: ");
            int n = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Introduzca el número de fases: ");
            int k = sc.nextInt();
    
            int[] primerArray = new int[n];
            int[] segundoArray = new int[n];
    
            for (int fase = 0; fase < k; fase++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < primerArray.length; i++) {
                    primerArray[i] = i + 1;
                }
            }
    
            procesar(primerArray,segundoArray);
            procesar(segundoArray,primerArray);
        }
        
        private static void procesar(int[] primerArray, int[] segundoArray){
            for (int i = 0; i < segundoArray.length; i++) {
                int sum = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < primerArray.length; j++) {
                    if (i != j) {
                        sum = sum + primerArray[j];
                    }
                }
                segundoArray[i] = sum;
                System.out.println(primerArray[i] + " - " + segundoArray[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Si no quieres invertirlos al llamar la función puedes hacer una copia de `segundoArray`:

```
procesar(primerArray,segundoArray);

//crear copia
primerArray = Arrays.copyOf(segundoArray,segundoArray.length);

procesar(primerArray,segundoArray);
```